# JS. Как получить statusText ответа?

Tags: javascript, http

Если отправлять запрос к API через Postman, то он он рядом с кодом выводит статус-текст ответа. Если же делать запрос из кода JS, то я не могу получить текст статуса. Что fetch, что XMLHttpRequest говорят, что statusText is Undefined. Как его достать?

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(response.statusText);` // вернет "OK" если сработал statusText

```
var myImage = document.querySelector('img');

var myRequest = new Request('flowers.jpg');

fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.statusText); // вернет "OK" если сработал
  response.blob().then(function(myBlob) {
    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
    myImage.src = objectURL;
  });
});
```